# Failing to debug with node-inspector - what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js

I have a javascript code that checks whether a point is inside a polygon. I am trying to debug it with node-inspector, following these steps:

In the first window:

```
PS Z:\dev> node-inspector.cmd
   info  - socket.io started
visit http://0.0.0.0:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging
```

In the second window:

```
PS Z:\dev\poc\SDR> node --debug-brk .\IsPointInside.js
debugger listening on port 5858
```

Now I navigate to http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858 in my Chrome browser.

What happens is that Chrome gets stuck `waiting for localhost` presenting me the empty screen.

I must add that I have successfully debugged the [r.js javascript optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) using the same steps before, but now I cannot debug it as well.

Answer (score 1):

according to [this](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/issues/104) there seems to be an order in which the components should be started.

Its application -> debugger -> web browser.

Could be your issue.

Comment: I stopped using the node-inspector, purchased a license of IntelliJ IDEA, which is perfectly capable to debug both NodeJS and browser (Chrome and FF) hosted JS code. It is very convenient. Debugging Javascript is more or less the same as debugging Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send a "debug on demand" command. Use this command:

kill -USR1 $PROCESSID